# couchdb in docker container: how to remove id from output

Tags: node.js, docker, couchdb

To begin with, I am new to couchdb and new to databases in general.I have a couchdb instance setup in a docker container. I have another docker container in the same box that has some nodeJS code that is talking to this couchdb instance.

Now, I am doing basic stuff like adding an entry and getting an entry from the db. To get an entry, this is what I do:

```
curl -X GET http://IP:5984/mydb/158
```

I get an output as follows:

```
{"_id":"156", "_rev":"1-47c19c00bee6417f36c7db2bc8607468", "name":{"given":["Itisha"], "family":["Iyengar"]}, "dob":"1981-06-01", "phone":{"value":"tel:312-116-1123"}, "address":{"line["147leverettmailcenter"], "city":"Naperville", "state":"IL", "postalCode":"02770"}, "SID":""}
```

I pass the data to another function that processes it further. However, I only want the actual data and don't want fields like _id and _rev.How do I do that? -

1. I read somewhere that I can log into the couchdb instance by doing http://localhost:5984/ from the machine where it is installed. Here I can edit the get script to make it return just the data and ignore the _id and _rev fields. However, I am running it from a docker container on Ubuntu. I do not have access to a UI through which I can make such changes. Is there an alternate way to do this?
2. If not, is there a way to parse the output and filter out the _id and _rev fields? As of now, I am doing this in a crude way by doing String.splice() and filtering out the data (after the _id and _rev fields) till the end. But I don't think this is a good way to do this and definitely not a good idea for actual production code.
   Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try marking some of your questions with correct answers as accepted (use the   symbol below the answer score). If there's a problem with my answer let me know in the comments

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, depending on your needs:

#### method 1

Use [_find](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html) by making a POST request to /db/_find and select the fields you want

```
curl -X POST -d '{"fields": ["name", "family", "dob", "phone", "address", "SID"]}' http://IP:5984/mydb/_find
```

The parameter `-d` is used to send the data to the POST request.
You may need to escape the quotes if you're running Windows.

#### method 2

Use a [view function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/index.html)

#### method 3

Process the results with a simple node program

```
const http = require("http");

http.get({
    host: 'IP',
    port: 5984
    path: '/mydb/158'
  }, function(response) {
       var body = '';
       response.on('data', function(d) {
         body += d;
       });

       response.on('end', function() {
         var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
         var result = {};

         for (var key in parsed) {
           if (key != "_id" && key != "_rev") {
             result[key] = parsed[key];      
           }
         }

         console.log(result);
       });
    }
);
```

The above code issues a GET request to your couchdb server, parses the JSON output and puts the results in a new object after ignoring the _id and _rev keys.

#### method 4

Process the output as a string. As you correctly pointed out, this is not a good solution. It's ugly, but it doesn't mean it can't be done. You could even pipe the output through `sed/awk/perl` and process the string there.

Comment: Sorry I could not get back. I tried method 1 which didn't work. I ended up fixing some other issues and did not get a chance to do this. I will try either method 1 or 2 soon and let you know.